# Ruby : Rubeque - difficult with *n or n

Tags: ruby

I'm doing  http://www.rubeque.com/problems/queue-continuum/solutions/51a26923ba804b00020000df and I spent a while there. I can't realize why this code doesn't pass

```
def initialize(queue)
  @q = queue
end

def pop(n=1)
  @q.shift(n)

end

def push(arr)
  arr.each { |x|
    @q.push(x)
  }
  return true
end

def to_a
  @q
end
```

but this works perfectly.

```
def initialize(queue)
  @q = queue
end

def pop(*n)
  @q.shift(*n)

end

def push(arr)
  @q.push(*arr)
  return true
end

def to_a
  @q
end
```

i'm totally confused about

```
def pop(*n)
  @q.shift(*n)

end
```

and

```
def push(arr)
  @q.push(*arr)
end
```

why should I take (arr) as array and than change it into... *arr which is Array of array? I'm confused, please help!

Comment: Was your code really formatted like this? Good formatting makes code easier to read. Bad formatting renders it completely unreadable. Yours was pretty much the bad one.

Comment: Thanks Sergio for fixing it. It wasn't like that. Coping process destroyed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splat works in two ways.

When receiving arguments, it combines arguments into an array.

```
def foo *args; args end
foo(1) # => [1]
foo(1, 2, 3) # => [1, 2, 3]
```

When giving arguments, it decomposes an array into arguments.

```
def bar x, y, z; y end
bar(*[1, 2, 3]) # => 2

def baz x; x end
baz(1) # => [1]
baz(1, 2, 3) # => Error
```

The `*arr` you are wondering is the latter case. It is not an object like `[1, 2, 3]` (hence, not an array of arrays). It is a part of arguments (like `1, 2, 3`) passed to a method.

There are other uses of splats (as in array literals, case statements, etc.), but their function is either of the two uses above.